# Break out of loop from console while in debug mode

Tags: python, loops, debugging, pycharm

I'm debugging some code in PyCharm by stepping through line-by-line. The code involves a long for-loop, but for debugging purposes, I don't need to iterate through the whole thing. Instead, I'd like to break out after a few iterations. I'm trying to figure out how to do so without modifying my code to have special debugging instructions.

Example for loop

```py
indices = range(10000, 0, -1)
for i, val in enumerate(indices):
     print(val) # I can tell that it's working after a few iterations
```

The first thing I tried was typing `break` in the debugging console when paused at the `print(val)` line. This resulted in a syntax error

> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

I also thought about using the debugging console line to modify the variable that I am enumerating over. For example, entering

```py
indices = []
```

This has no effect on the iterator. Apparently, the iterator has an independent copy of the variable.

In another language, Java for example, I would take advantage of the termination condition, but python loops don't have a termination condition. I could rewrite my for-loop as a while-loop so that it would have an explicit termination condition, but that would obfuscate the code.

The other option would be to add special debugging instructions. For example,

```py
mode = 'debug'
indices = range(10000, 0, -1)
for i, val in enumerate(indices):
     print(val) # I can tell that it's working after a few iterations
     if mode == 'debug' and i % 10:
         break
```

I dislike doing this because inevitably, one of these special instructions gets left in after debugging is finished and mucks everything up.

Do I have any other options to break out of the loop from the debug console or without modifying the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dislike doing this because inevitably, one of these special instructions gets left in after debugging is finished and mucks everything up.

Python `for` loops just aren't designed to be [changed during execution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), besides hard coding `break`, `return` or throwing `StopIteration`. (You are debugging, so either change the range in the loops expression list, or let it run through). The reason being the advantages of straightforward simplicity outweigh exposing the `for` loop counter - see [PEP 212](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0212/#introduction).

Comment: I initially didn't understand that you were suggesting adding a function that was called by the conditional breakpoint. My edit attempts to make this more clear.

Comment: After more consideration, this solution still only allows me to customize breakpoints further. I want to `break` out of the for-loop and leave the for-loop prematurely. Setting breakpoints is not an issue. I think your last paragraph contains the relevant info, "Python loops just aren't designed to be changed during execution".

Comment: Otherwise, your solution can be reduced to a conditional breakpoint `i == stop` which eliminates the need for an additional counter function, and inserts a breakpoint at `stop` iterations.

Comment: 1º reducing to `i==stop` won't be useful because in most cases `for` loops don't have an `i` (unlike Java, C, etc) that's why I showed a solution that keeps a counter outside the loop. 2º Your 2 requirements were strict: A. don't alter the source, B. break out of the `for` loop from inside the function scope. As I tried to demonstrate the Python language itself doesn't have provisions to fully satisfy both conditions (a simple `if`+`break` would satisfy, but then you'd be altering the source). You could simply `import` the extra break-point function, but even then you change 1 source line.

Comment: I understand now that this functionality is not supported, but your proposed conditional breakpoint does not address how to break out of a for loop. It simply adds another way of pausing execution. I think only your last paragraph is relevant to the original question, and it answers it: it's not possible. If you remove the rest of the answer, I'll accept it.