# Debugging "in the middle of a huge loop" (python/pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

Asking this hoping there is a solution. So I have a large iteration and in the middle, I get some undesirable results. So Suppose

```
for i in range(10000):
     somecode
```

and when i reaches 5000, I want to see what's going on that "somecode" generates these results. Is there a way to break into this for loop from iteration 5000 onward?

Comment: `if i == 5000: breakpoint()` perhaps?

Comment: In PyCharm, you can set a condition on a breakpoint, have you rightclicked one?

Comment: Also see [Break out of loop from console while in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65931945)